# in pyspark > why SparkSession with "master('local')" need internet connection?

Tags: pyspark

I am new with pyspark .

I want to know why SparkSession with   `master('local')` need internet connection?
I thougut that it should run the code only in my local computer.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder 
   .master('local[8]') 
   .appName('myAppName') 
   .getOrCreate()
```

and what happend if I dont close the session before I turned off the computer?

Comment: What makes you think Spark needs internet connection to work locally? If you are running on Windows and getting notifications to enable the firewall, that's because Spark opens a couple of listening sockets even when running locally.

Comment: I run the code with connection and without.  with connection it run perfect. and without    it make many WARN massages and also when I try afterward  to read file it  it says : ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.     and also : An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:50267)